# Installing pari-gp without pulling the X server packages

Tags: apt

"pari-gp" is a command line computer algebra system capable of plotting graphs. Its documentation is formatted as TeX files due to multiple mathematical formulas. However, I don't want to use these functions: I just need to perform some computations.

Execution of `apt install pari-gp` isn't a way of installing this on my text based Debian machine (without desktop environment), as it tries to pull a lot of X related packages:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid-fallback fonts-lmodern fonts-noto-mono libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libdrm2 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl
  libfontenc1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgs9
  libgs9-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libice6 libijs-0.35 libipc-system-simple-perl
  libjbig2dec0 libkpathsea6 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.9 libnet-dbus-perl libnspr4
  libnss3 libopenjp2-7 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpciaccess0 libpoppler64
  libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsensors4 libsm6 libsynctex1 libtcl8.6 libtexlua52
  libtexluajit2 libtie-ixhash-perl libtk8.6 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc libutempter0
  libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxft2
  libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpm4 libxshmfence1
  libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libzzip-0-13 lmodern
  pari-doc pari-elldata pari-galdata pari-seadata poppler-data t1utils tcl
  tcl8.6 texlive-base texlive-binaries tk tk8.6 x11-common x11-utils
  x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps xdg-utils xterm
Suggested packages:
  fonts-noto liblcms2-utils lm-sensors libunicode-map8-perl
  libunicode-string-perl xml-twig-tools pari-gp2c pari-galpol poppler-utils
  ghostscript fonts-japanese-mincho | fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-japanese-gothic | fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
  fonts-arphic-uming fonts-nanum tcl-tclreadline gv | postscript-viewer
  perl-tk xpdf-reader | pdf-viewer mesa-utils nickle cairo-5c xorg-docs-core
  gvfs-bin xfonts-cyrillic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid-fallback fonts-lmodern fonts-noto-mono libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libdrm2 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl
  libfontenc1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgs9
  libgs9-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libice6 libijs-0.35 libipc-system-simple-perl
  libjbig2dec0 libkpathsea6 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.9 libnet-dbus-perl libnspr4
  libnss3 libopenjp2-7 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpciaccess0 libpoppler64
  libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsensors4 libsm6 libsynctex1 libtcl8.6 libtexlua52
  libtexluajit2 libtie-ixhash-perl libtk8.6 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc libutempter0
  libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxft2
  libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpm4 libxshmfence1
  libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libzzip-0-13 lmodern
  pari-doc pari-elldata pari-galdata pari-gp pari-seadata poppler-data t1utils
  tcl tcl8.6 texlive-base texlive-binaries tk tk8.6 x11-common x11-utils
  x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps xdg-utils xterm
0 upgraded, 89 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 149 MB of archives.
After this operation, 466 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

Can I somehow install what I want without X packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pari-gp`](https://tracker.debian.org/pari-gp) on its own should only pull in a limited number of X11 packages (`libx11-6`, `libx11-data` and `libxcb1`). The other packages are pulled in because of `pari-gp`’s “recommended” dependencies; this includes in particular `pari-doc` which pulls in TeX Live.

To avoid this, run

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends pari-gp
```

Comment: I couldn't find this option in manpages, because I was reading them for apt, not apt-get... (+1)